# Excel VBA - Importing numbers into Access table as text

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel VBA code which reads a column in Excel and imports the values to a table in Access:

```
Dim Cn As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\myDatabase.accdb"
Cn.Open strConnection

For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (" & Cells(i, 1).Value & ")"
Next i

Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
```

The problem is that even though the values in the column are technically numbers (0001234, 0123456, 0001, etc) the column is formatted as Text, and the field in the Access table is formatted as Text. But the code above is still importing them as numbers, which drops the leading 0(s). Is there a way to force them to import as Text values?

Thanks!!

---

**EDIT**: I tried putting a single quote in front of the values in the column (ex: '0001234 instead of 0001234), but they're still being imported as numbers.

**EDIT2**: I also tried this:

```
Dim Cn As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String
Dim CellValue as String
Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\myDatabase.accdb"
Cn.Open strConnection

For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    CellValue = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (" & CellValue & ")"
Next i

Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
```

But the values are still getting the leading 0's dropped upon import.

**EDIT3 - Solved!!** I had to put double quotes around the `Cells(i, 1).Value`. Now the leading 0's are staying put!

```
Dim Cn As Object
Dim strSql As String
Dim strConnection As String

Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\CarrierAudit.accdb"
Cn.Open strConnection

For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO Pinnacol_NDC VALUES (""" & Cells(i, 1).Value & """)"
Next i

Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
```

Comment: That throws an `Automation Error`

Comment: Can you do something like `Dim cellValue as String` then `cellValue = Cells(i, 1).Value`, then in your `Cn.Execute`, repleace `Cells(i, 1).Value` with `cellValue`?  I don't know if this will make a difference.

Comment: @nhgrif That makes complete sense, but it still converts the string to number upon import.

Comment: `cellValue = Cells(i, 1).Value.toString("D8")` if `Value` has a `toString` method (I'm not 100% comfortable with VBA).  And if that works, you probably don't even need the `cellValue` variable.  Just add `toString("D8")` to what you have already.

Comment: Or better yet, `Dim cellValue as Int` then `"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (" & cellValue.toString("D8") & ")"` should work.

Comment: That throws a `Compile Error - Invalid Qualifier`

Comment: I think `CStr(CellValue)` is what we're looking for, but it STILL drops the leading 0's

Comment: Try `ToString` rather than `toString`, I forgot VBA likes to capitalize things.

Comment: I don't think `.ToString` works .. I get an `Invalid Qualifier` error. `CStr` is the VBA thing that turns an Int to a String, but `CStr` still drops the leading 0's.

Comment: `Format(cellValue, "0000000")` Try that.

Comment: THIS DID IT! `Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO Pinnacol_NDC VALUES (""" & CellValue & """)"` .. had to put the extra double quotes around the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the string in the line

```
Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (" & CellValue & ")"
```

will evaluate to, for 0001234:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (0001234)
```

because there are no quotation marks around the 0001234, it is treated by SQL as a number and not a string.
Change that line of code to read:

```
Cn.Execute "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (""" & CellValue & """)"
```

The extra quotation marks "" are the VBA string escape sequence to indicate that a double quotation mark should be placed into the string when it is evaluated, generating the following:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("0001234")
```

which will cause SQL to treat it as a text string and insert correctly.

Comment: I figured this out right before you posted it, but I'm going to accept it since it's the right answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully it will help anyone else who is looking for the same thing.

Comment: I agree. This site has helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CellValue = Cells(i, 1).Text` to access the text value of a cell

Comment: Thanks .. I just tried that, and it still drops the leading 0's from the cell value. I had to put double quotes around the whole thing (updated the original post)

Comment: You can change the number formatting of the cell to "000000" if you want a number with six digits with the zeroes in front